# Python multiprocessing script dies after several hours of running

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Am having a python3.4 multiprocessing script that runs ok and then dies out on me. For example, it runs for about 4 hours then when I come back to it I find its no longer processing.

As opposed to earlier, Top now shows a gazillion processes running in the background. I ordered them and found a bunch of python3.4 processes.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
13322 root      20   0  888716 316456   3272 S   0.0  7.8   0:27.09 python3.4
13325 root      20   0  888480 316212   3272 S   0.0  7.8   0:26.54 python3.4
13327 root      20   0  873136 300836   3272 S   0.0  7.4   0:14.83 python3.4
13309 root      20   0  651924 299896   3244 S   0.0  7.4   0:23.38 python3.4
13305 root      20   0  651924 299888   3244 S   0.0  7.4   0:22.17 python3.4
13287 root      20   0 1055324  46800   6268 S   0.0  1.2   0:03.97 python3.4
13414 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.3  1.0   0:01.92 python3.4
13415 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.0  1.0   0:01.82 python3.4
13416 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.0  1.0   0:01.85 python3.4
13417 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.0  1.0   0:01.88 python3.4
13418 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.3  1.0   0:01.86 python3.4
13419 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.7  1.0   0:01.89 python3.4
13420 root      20   0  834128  41344   3264 S   2.0  1.0   0:01.83 python3.4
#About 60 others truncated for brevity
13293 root      20   0  165356  31632   3260 S   0.0  0.8   0:02.46 python3.4
13291 root      20   0  165364  31592   3256 S   0.0  0.8   0:02.37 python3.4
13295 root      20   0  165356  31584   3256 S   0.0  0.8   0:02.44 python3.4
```

Below is the setup code to start the processing. I've observed using top that upon each subsequent call to `process_score`, existing python3.4 processes remain and a new bunch of 8 come up. Eventually, I think the processes build up and eat up my resources and cause the main script to "freeze".

Its my thinking that part of the magic of `pool.map` is terminating child processes on exit and I don't have to keep track and terminate them myself? As such, how do I ensure that the child processes are terminated? Searching in stackoverflow doesn't give much information on terminating child processes while using pool.map

```
While True
    id_list = get_student_ids()
    if id_list == []:
        break
    else:
        #Multiprocessing starts here:
        num_of_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_of_consumers)
        col_list_insert = pool.map(student_score.process_score, id_list)
```

Comment: It'd probably be more helpful to remove *everything* below the setup code (it's not really helpful), and posting `process_score` instead.

Comment: It's very strange that you'd only see one process running when you have an eight process pool - Python will automatically restart any process in a pool that unexpectedly dies almost instantly. Are you sure there was only *one* process? If that was the case, why would pressing Ctrl+C show tracebacks from worker processes? The most likely problem I can think of is something causing one of the processes to be killed unexpectedly (something other than a Python exception, which would get handled properly). If that occurs, the `map` call will hang forever.

Comment: @dano: "python will automatically restart any process in a pool that unexpectedly dies almost instantly".  Really?  I've never heard of that - do you have a reference?  I can't even see how that would work - if the processes were connected via pipes or queues, wouldn't it just corrupt?

Comment: @Gerrat Best I can do is point you to [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4be39be5230c/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l320) responsible for doing it. You can try it for yourself, too. Create a pool in the interactive interpreter, do a `for p in pool._pool: print p.pid`. Kill one of those pids, and try again. You'll find a new worker has replaced it. Note that this very sophisticated, it just adds a new worker if it sees one is missing. If the dead worker was in the middle of handling a task, that task is lost forever.

Comment: @Gerrat I think the main reason for its existence is to make the `mastasksperchild` keyword argument work properly, as opposed to recovering from unexpected failures. It's actually detrimental in that case. `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` does the exact opposite thing when a process unexpectedly dies - it puts the pool into a broken state, where any request sent to it raises `BrokenProcessPool`. `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't have that feature simply because no one cared enough to implement it, it seems. See [issue9205](http://bugs.python.org/issue9205) for more info.

Comment: @dano:  Really interesting.  I wonder why that isn't documented (about the restarting).

Comment: @Gerrat Not sure. It could very well just be an oversight, especially since I think the behavior is just a side-effect of how `maxtasksperchild` is implemented.

Comment: @dano got more information. when the process seems frozen, there are actually many `python3.4` processes runnning. I've edited to question to reflect this. So question now is how to ensure that all sub processes are killed on completion of one cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeatedly creating new `Pool` objects in the while loop. Instead, create the pool *once*, outside of the while loop, and just call `pool.map` repeatedly. This will mean the same 8 processes get used for the entire life of your program, rather than a new set of 8 constantly being launched.

Comment: That was a fundamental understanding that I had got wrong. Thanks.